# Multiple webpart with MGT Control not working in single page in React SPFX Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, error, spfx-webparts, microsoft-graph

I have used MGT Person Control in my two SPFx web parts.

If I add the single web part on one page and another web part in another page, both web parts are working properly.

And if I add both the web parts on single page than first web part loading properly and second web part throwing below issue:

> Original error: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': the name "mgt-mock-provider" has already been used with this registry**.

- Environment - SharePoint Online
- Framework - React
- SPFx Solution

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which version of SPFx & `@microsoft/mgt`, you are using?

Comment: Hi Ganesh,

I am using below version
SPFX : 1.11.0
MGT: 2.1.0
MGT-React:2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

This is a issue with `CustomElementRegistry`. Seems like it has been resolved with latest updates to library.

Try importing below `mgt` imports are from:

```
@microsoft/mgt-spfx
```

OR

```
@microsoft/mgt-react/dist/es6/spfx
```

You can follow this thread for more information: [[BUG] Multiple Web Parts with SharePoint Provider in the same page error](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues/229)

Comment: Hi Ganesh, Actually I am using below import
 import {Person , PersonCardInteraction } from '@microsoft/mgt-react';

I have also provide version of spfx and Mgt version above 

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try suggestions given in my answer & github issue link? Try importing from `@microsoft/mgt-spfx` OR `@microsoft/mgt-react/dist/es6/spfx ` library instead of `@microsoft/mgt-react`.